# 'at' or 'in' used in a phrase

Tags: prepositions

I am having problems choosing between those two in a phrase I use a lot at work. I am gonna go straight to the example

'Your order status has changed to 'At delivery site at CH 8060 Zurich'

I work in logistics and I send clients updates like this for every job. Postcode and city name can be anything as I operate worldwide.

Question is. Which one is better/corrext here for 'At delivery site in' or 'At delivery site at'

Thanks for your help

Comment: My choice would be At . . . at. The package is at the delivery site at City Postcode.

Comment: Some people observe a convention of using _in_ for a large city and _at_ for smaller places.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be 'at delivery site in Zurich'

"at" is generally used to refer to a specific address or a point or a general location; it can also be used when you are at the top, bottom or end of something.With specific address or location , use at

e.g I am at 12 NY Street

I am at home

I am at the entrance

"in" is used for enclosed spaces or a location which is inside of something.

My phone is in my bag

We live in Brazil

As a rule, use "at" when you view that location as a point and use "in" with the bigger location which encapsulates this smaller location

e.g I am at a village in Thailand